# Issue with JavaScript/jQuery event ordering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

I'm having an issue with events not firing in the intended order. I have an event on an input element for focus and focusout. The .focus() shows some content, the .focusout() hides it. I want to be able to .click() on some of the data that I'm showing with the .focus(), however when I click on it, the first thing to fire is the .focusout() event handler, and for some reason the action of hiding the content screws with the .click() event handler.

Here are my event listeners:

```
$('#content').click(function(evt) {
    alert('Yay');
});

$('input').focus(function() {
    $('#content').show();
});

$('input').focusout(function() {
    $('#content').hide();
});
```

If any of this is confusing, you can see the exact behavior in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r7wjoq8/2/). When you click the input box, the red box shows. But if you then try to activate the click listener on the red box, the .focusout() takes priority and hides the content, and no .click() event transpires.

Desired behavior: Click on input, content shows, click on content, content click listener fires.

Comment: it goes to hide before it is clicked and so click event is not fired because it is not clicked

Comment: Not sure I know exactly what you want, but is this close http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/etckaehL/?

Comment: @j08691 More or less. You fixed the issue, but I was more curious about *why* it was happening that way. I thought events were FIFO.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam The events, as I understood it, happen in a FIFO queue. Since I define the click event first, I assumed it would be called first.

Comment: you can use @guest271314 solution which make little delay to hide the content so that click event fire

Comment: the event is fired at ordering its OK. But your click event is not fired because #content is not clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
$('#content').click(function(evt) {
    alert('Yay'); 
});

$('input').focus(function() {
    $('#content').show();
});

$('input').on("focusout", function() {
    $('#content').delay(100).hide(1);
});
```

```js
$('#content').click(function(evt) {
    alert('Yay'); 
});

$('input').focus(function() {
    $('#content').show();
});

$('input').on("focusout", function() {
    $('#content').delay(100).hide(1);
});
```

```css
#content {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: none;
}

#content {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">    
</div>

<input type="search">
```

Comment: Except it doesn't hide the content div if you click anywhere outside of it.

Comment: Yeah, this solves the issue. I guess I wasn't really looking for a direct solution (which is nice to have, don't get me wrong) but rather to understand what's going on and why the events aren't FIFO.

Comment: @bawjensen See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout _"An element is **about to lose focus** (bubbles)."_  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click  _"A pointing device button has been pressed **and released** on an element."_

Comment: @bawjensen `focusout` appear to fire _before_ pointing device `click` `event` has been "released"

Comment: @guest271314 That was exactly the explanation I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**->
This is what you want :

```
$("#content").click(function (evt)
{
    if (evt.target == document.getElementById("content"))
    {  alert("Yay");
       $('#content').show();
       $('input').focus();
    }
});


$('input').focus(function() {
    $('#content').show();
});

$('input').focusout(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){ $('#content').hide(); }, 100);    
});
```

This works.

Comment: Except it doesn't hide the content div if you click anywhere outside of it.

Comment: The intent is not to hide the content upon clicking on it. The content should show/hide based on whether or not the input is focused, and still be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$('#content').click(function(evt) {
  clearTimeout($(this).data('focusTimer'))
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('#content').length == 0) {
    $('#content').hide();
  }
})

$('input').focus(function() {
  $('#content').show();
});

$('input').focusout(function() {
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#content').hide();
  }, 500)
  $('#content').data('focusTimer', timer);
});
```

```css
#content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
#content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<input type="search">
```